# Why not combine the events for the same day?

Tags: support, reputation-history

I was initially going to ask why I have separate lines for events for the same day, as shown below

[image: separate event lines]

But when I visited the profile page for the second time about 3 minutes later, I saw this:

[image: combined events lines]

So, why did the former occur and why did it later become the latter? Database process running at specific times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I can see from the yellow highlight, it was showing you the changes you hadn't seen on the 'Reputation' tab yet. After you saw them, it rolled them into one.